# Prove that $N \subset Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Assume that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $N \cap G'=\{e\}$.  Prove that $N \subset Z(G)$.

Note 1: $Z(G)$ is the center of the group $G$, and $G'$ is the set of all commutators of $G$.

Note 2: Assume that $n \in N$. We want to show that for all $g \in G,$  $ng=gn$. But, I don't know how to use the fact that $N \cap G'=\{e\}$ to reach this.

Any hints? suggestions? answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n\in N,g\in G$.
Then $$[n,g]=n^{-1}(g^{-1}ng)\in N\cap G'=1$$
So $n$ commutes with $g$.
Since $g$ is arbitrary, $n\in Z(G)$.
Hence $N\leq Z(G)$.

Further explanation if you can't get the hint

> (i) $[n,g]$ is a commutator hence $[n,g]\in G'$
>  (ii) Since $N$ is normal in $G$, $g^{-1}ng\in N$, hence $[n,g]=n^{-1}g^{-1}ng\in N$
>  From these two points, $[n,g]\in N\cap G'=1$ which means that $n^{-1}g^{-1}ng=1$ and hence $ng=gn$.